# Reading in a file with Google datalab

Tags: google-api-python-client, google-cloud-datalab

I am trying to use Google Datalab to read in a file in ipython notebook, the basic pd.read_csv() as I can't find the path of the file. I have it locally and also uploaded it to google cloud storage in a bucket.

I ran the following commands to understand where I am

```
os.getcwd()
```

gives '/content/myemail@gmail.com'

```
os.listdir('/content/myemail@gmail.com')
```

gives ['.git', '.gitignore', 'datalab', 'Hello World.ipynb', '.ipynb_checkpoints']

Answer (score 10):

The following reads the contents of the object into a string variable called `text`:

```
%%storage read --object "gs://path/to/data.csv" --variable text
```

Then

```
from cStringIO import StringIO
mydata = pd.read_csv(StringIO(text)) 
mydata.head()
```

Hopefully Pandas will support `"gs://"` URLs (as it does for `s3://` currently to allow reading directly from Google Cloud storage.

I have found the following docs really helpful:

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/datalab/tree/master/content/datalab/tutorials

Hope that helps (just getting started with Datalab too, so maybe someone will have a cleaner method soon).

Comment: I get this ERROR: Cell magic `%%storage` not found (But line magic `%storage` exists, did you mean that instead?)?

Comment: also looks like I have to specify the path, but that is what is unknown to me :)

Comment: `%%storage` does work for me.   The two bits of code are in separate cells in the notebook, `%%` is a cell magic.  Just to clarify the path, `gs://path/the/data.csv` points to the file on Google Cloud Storage in you bucket, not locally on your laptop, so the one you uploaded.  `gs://bucket/file.csv`

Comment: My Datalab version (from clicking the "i" top right) gives: Version: 0.5.20151127
Based on Jupyter (formerly IPython) 4, incase there are any version mis-matches going on.

Comment: ok so it started working for whatever reason 
%%storage read --object "https://console.cloud.google.com/m/cloudstorage/b/project1/o/dataset.csv" gives an error of storage read: error: argument -v/--variable is required; tried to put a variable name beefore and after but doesn't seem to work

Comment: Did you include the --variable argument? That specifies the name of the Python variable that will be assigned the content of the GCS object.

Comment: @Chris the github link is down.. also is there a way to specify the encoding?

Comment: It looks like datalab has moved to its own home https://github.com/googledatalab/notebooks

Answer (score 1):

You can also run BigQuery queries directly against CSV files in Cloud Storage by creating a FederatedTable wrapper object. That is described here:

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/datalab/blob/master/content/datalab/tutorials/BigQuery/Using%20External%20Tables%20from%20BigQuery.ipynb

Comment: but that requires to specify the path? I am just confused as to where this csv file I upload to storage 'lives'

Answer (score 0):

I uploaded my *Iris.csv* to my datalab root directory.

Then like you mentioned in your question ran the following code cell.

```
os.getcwd()
```

I got **'/content/datalab/docs'**

Then i ran the following code cell.

```
iris = pd.read_csv('/content/datalab/Iris.csv')
print(iris)
```

It worked for me.