# How can i load my csv from google dataLab to a pandas data frame?

Tags: google-cloud-datalab

Here is what i tried: 
(ipython notebook, with python2.7)

```
import gcp
import gcp.storage as storage
import gcp.bigquery as bq
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

sample_bucket_name = gcp.Context.default().project_id + '-datalab'
sample_bucket_path = 'gs://' + sample_bucket_name 
sample_bucket_object = sample_bucket_path + '/myFile.csv'
sample_bucket = storage.Bucket(sample_bucket_name)
df = bq.Query(sample_bucket_object).to_dataframe()
```

Which fails.
would you have any leads what i am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In addition to @Flair's comments about %gcs, I got the following to work for the Python 3 kernel:

```
    import pandas as pd
    from io import BytesIO

    %gcs read --object "gs://[BUCKET ID]/[FILE].csv" --variable csv_as_bytes

    df = pd.read_csv(BytesIO(csv_as_bytes))
    df.head()
```

Answer (score 9):

Based on the [datalab source code](https://github.com/googledatalab/pydatalab/blob/master/datalab/bigquery/_query.py) `bq.Query()` is primarily used to execute BigQuery SQL queries. In in terms of reading a file from Google Cloud Storage (GCS), one potential solution is to use the datalab `%gcs` line magic function to read the csv from GCS into a local variable. Once you have the data in a variable, you can then use the `pd.read_csv()` function to convert the csv formatted data into a pandas DataFrame. The following should work:

```
import pandas as pd
from StringIO import StringIO

# Read csv file from GCS into a variable
%gcs read --object gs://cloud-datalab-samples/cars.csv --variable cars

# Store in a pandas dataframe
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(cars))
```

There is also a related stackoverflow question at the following link:
[Reading in a file with Google datalab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34713864/reading-in-a-file-with-google-datalab/34721589#34721589)

Answer (score 0):

You could also use Dask to extract and then load the data into, let's say, a Jupyter Notebook running on GCP.

Make sure you have Dask is installed.

`conda install dask #conda`

`pip install dask[complete] #pip`

`import dask.dataframe as dd #Import`

`dataframe = dd.read_csv('gs://bucket/datafile.csv') #Read CSV data`

`dataframe2 = dd.read_csv('gs://bucket/path/*.csv') #Read parquet data`

This is all you need to load the data.

You can filter and manipulate data with Pandas syntax now.

`dataframe['z'] = dataframe.x + dataframe.y`

`dataframe_pd = dataframe.compute()`