# Google Datalab) How to read multiple csv files existing in Google Cloud Storage by pandas read_csv() to?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-datalab

I found the solution for reading a "single" csv file in a `Datalab` : [How can i load my csv from google dataLab to a pandas data frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37990467/how-can-i-load-my-csv-from-google-datalab-to-a-pandas-data-frame)

But I wonder how I could read "multiple" csv files in `Datalab`.

What I tried is like this :

```
variable_list = ['IBM', 'SPY']
for variable in variable_list:
  file_path = "gs://chois-trader-bucket/data/" + variable + ".csv"
  %%storage read --object file_path --variable variable
```

But this one failed because python variable is not compatible with magic command.

How can I deal with multiple csv files effectively?

Answer (score 1):

You can use ***variables*** enclosed in braces.

```
e.g) %storage read --object {file_path} --variable variable
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can do a union of all the csv files in a folder using a one liner in bash as such (assuming no headers in the csv files) :

`cat *.csv > unioned_file_name.csv`

Then import that one file into pandas.