# Loading multiple CSVs into Google Datalab from Cloud Storage

Tags: google-cloud-datalab

Some variants of the question have been [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37990467/how-can-i-load-my-csv-from-google-datalab-to-a-pandas-data-frame?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45532796/google-datalab-how-to-read-multiple-csv-files-existing-in-google-cloud-storage?noredirect=1&lq=1), which I've successfully used

Nevertheless, I have a slightly different problem. I've exported 1GB of data using BigQuery into Google Storage. This export is split between 5 csv files, with each dataset containing column names (I think this is what causing things to break).

The code that I have is:

```
# Run import
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from io import BytesIO

# Grab the file from the cloud storage
variable_list = ['part1', 'part2','part3','part4','part5']
for variable in variable_list:
  file_path = "gs://[Bucket-name]/" + variable + ".csv"
  %gcs read --object {file_path} --variable byte_data

# Read the dataset
data = pd.read_csv(BytesIO(byte_data), low_memory=False)
```

However, when I call `len(data)` I don't get the full amount of rows back. The above code only seems to load 1 file.

I can load 5 different data frames and simply combine them in pandas by `data=[df1, df2, df3, df4, df5]` but it seems very ugly.

Comment: My initial thought is that `byte_data` is being overwritten in each iteration. Could you create another python variable to store the full contents(where you can append `byte_data` after each iteration) ?

Comment: @AnthoniosPartheniou type(byte_data) returns that it's a bytes object. But if I create the empty bytes object full_data = bytes() , it doesn't have append. I tried changing full_data to list but I get: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'

Comment: Try using `bytearray` or alternatively search for 'byte concatenation' .

Answer (score 0):

I have found this and adopted for my cases. I run over all files in bucket (folder):

```
from google.datalab import Context
import google.datalab.storage as storage
import pandas as pd

try:
    from StringIO import StringIO
except ImportError:
    from io import BytesIO as StringIO

bucket_folder = 'ls_w'

df = pd.DataFrame()                # Final dataframe
for obj in bucket.objects():       # loop in all objects of the bucket
    if '/' not in obj.key:           # add other options to exclude other files
                                     # in this case it looks only at bucket level
                                     # not into subfolders!
        fn = obj.key                   # created file name variable (optional)
        print(obj.key)

        bites = 'gs://%s/%s' % (bucket_folder, fn)
        %gcs read --object $bites --variable data

        tdf = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data))  # read 

        df = pd.concat([df, tdf])          # concatenate results
```